# CSS flexbox 3 boxes - one sidebar

Tags: html, css, layout, sidebar, flexbox

It is possible to achieve something like this with flexbox:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmvZN.png (I can't put image directly...)

with that structure:

```html
<main>
  <section class="Div1">
  </section>
  <section class="Div2">
  </section>
  <aside class="Div3">
  </aside>
</main>
```

?

I can change order of elements inside  but I CAN NOT add any additional elements (like wrapper for Div1 and Div2, which will make problem solved).

I would like to change order of elements for mobile devices (Div3 between 1. and 2.), but for higher resolutions I need sidebar...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using flexbox only for sorting blocks on mobile devices and for higher resolutions build layout without it?

[What I suggest on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhlobo/qjbzLuo8/).

```
main {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.Div1 {order: 1;}
.Div2 {order: 3;}
.Div3 {order: 2;}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    main {
        display: block;
    }
    main:after {
        display: block;
        content: '\0020';
        clear: both;
    }
    .Div1, .Div2 {
        width: 60%;  
        float: left;
    }
    .Div3 {
        margin-left: 60%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be nice in real life, but I want to do it with flexbox only for training purposes... And it seems, that flexbox isn't perfect cure for layout problems ;/

Answer (score 0):

Well, Flexbox is **not** almighty tool, but you can do a lot more with it than without it.

The layout you want to do is quite easy to make, but if you want something more like change left column to 3 or 4... elements, you have to make another solution.

Simple solution for your problem may be the code **below**, but it is **"static"**!

```css
html, body, .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

#alfa { background: red; }
#beta { background: green; }
#gama { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="alfa">a</div>
  <div id="beta">b</div>
  <div id="gama">c</div>
</div>
```

If you want more dynamic solution, I think you have to make element for each column which will contain other elements. Something like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="column">
        <div id="alfa">a</div>
        <div id="beta">b</div>
    </div>

    <div id="column">
        <div id="gama">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```